# NSIS, Do not show uac dialog

Tags: nsis

After installation of the program, can not make uac dialog box disappear when the program is run?

Can I grant administrator privileges to install and have it run automatically at install time?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bypass UAC, the user is supposed to be in control of their computer, that is the whole point of UAC! If you want to do machine wide changes that require administrator privileges there is no way around it, the user has to elevate with UAC at least once.

If you want the installed application to run elevated automatically then you must write a custom [service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) that can be started on demand. When a administrator starts your application un-elevated the application must start your service and ask it to launch a elevated instance. The service must then call `CreateProcessAsUser` with the linked elevated token. This is too difficult for most developers and most applications just have to accept the fact that they must display a UAC prompt when they are started.